# Chrome parses the url incorrectly

Tags: google-chrome

This is how I am adding image tag under div

```
<img src='/files/images/remove.gif' border='0' " + 
               "  onClick='function(\"" + url + "\");' />";
```

When I open my page in Firefox, everything works fine and here the HTML gets generated in FF

```
<div class="myclass"><img border="0" onclick="myfunction(&quot;http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc/attachments/1d28bc6b-f637-426f-8bca-e27f1c6f2ed9/debug.txt&quot;);" src="/files/images/remove.gif">&nbsp;
</div>
```

But in Chrome HTML gets generated like this

```
<div class="myclass"><img src="/files/images/remove.gif" border="0" onclick="myfunction(" http:="" 127.0.0.1:8080="" abc="" attachments="" 1d28bc6b-f637-426f-8bca-e27f1c6f2ed9="" debug.txt");"="">&nbsp;
</div>
```

See the url it add extra quotes and = sign.

Can anyone please help me to understand what's wrong here, any workaround/solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you replace your two `&quot;` with `&#39;`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first, it looks like a bug in your script that emits the contents of the `onclick`. But then, it'd show up also in other browsers..

However, let's try from this view and assume it is a bug in your code, not Chrome.

Is the `onclick` generated by JS code, or on the server? If on JS, then please show us the code that generated and set that `onclick` handler, just to be sure it is correct.

OTOH, if it is generated on the server (ie. PHP, ASP, Ruby, ..), then have you tried peeking what exactly is sent over the wire? Open Chrome's DeveloperTools, go to "network" and refresh the page. Then watch the 'responses' and check if the HTML code embedded in them is correct. If it is incorrect, then look for a bug in the serverside scripts. If HTML seen in responses is correct, then indeed it is the browser.

If this is the latter case - the fact that HTMLInspector shows you the tag/link as damaged, it does not mean it has to malfunction. The Inspector is only a software too, so it may have some bugs in parsing/displaying - but the HTML tag may be correct and work properly. I've seen similar mis-displays a couple of times with various URLs before, but the links always worked properly. Try opening the ChromeConsole and $jquerying the URL out of that onclick. It might happen that you'll get the correct result - in that case, that's just presentation bug and the click/link should work properly - so ignore it or report to Google as a bug. Were the obtained URL incorrect, I'd double- or triplecheck the HTML in Network/Response to ensure that it really really as properly formatted, and then I'd call it a bug and try to work it around - i.e. by setting it via JS in onload, etc..

Comment: OnClick is generated by JS code like this

      <img src='/files/images/remove.gif' border='0' " + 
                   "  onClick='function(\"" + url + "\");' />";

Answer (score 0):

You are using some server infrastructure in between that is not pure HTML or JS, so we can't help properly.  You have onClick (looks like .net), +" " + in the middle, which is not pure HTML.

I created a replication here: http://jsbin.com/ubacak/latest Note, I changed your code and just had it as pure js + html and all is fine.

Comment: Yes, this is not pure JS and HTML. Thanks for your comment. I will debug this my side.